# Working with inbound mail(Receiving email) in Laravel for multiple smtps

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have requirement where user can register and put there smtp details(email,password,port,smtp mail server). With the help of those spmt details I need to send and show the received email in the dashboard. I have figure out a way to send the emails using the users smtp details but having issue with showing the received emails in the portal. So is there a way to get  the received  emails of different smtp in Laravel.

Thanks

Comment: Please check the protocols: SMTP is made for **sending** mails, and will not help you to read a inbox

Comment: so what can be done to get the received emails.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is not SMTP (which is used to **send emails**), but a library that can read emails using POP3/IMAP/NNTP protocols.

php-imap is one such library. You can find more about installation and usage here: https://packagist.org/packages/php-imap/php-imap

Please post another question if you have problems implementing it, and supply your code.